# Map Info: Thematic Mapping Symbols part printing

Tags: thematic-map

I have produced a series of thematic maps for graduated housing figures, using a symbol which I customized, in three different tables displayed in a layout.

This looks fine in the map window, although the symbols are sized much larger than in the layout and do overlap, in order to be a reasonably large size in the layout window.

All looks fine in the layout window, no overlapping. However, when printed, a couple of the symbols have parts missing. One has the top half and the other the right hand half. The symbols for these tables are small dots and don't overlap.

Any ideas please?

Comment: How did you customise the symbols? what changes did you make?